# FUSE calls getattr on special paths on Mac

Tags: macos, fuse, osxfuse

I'm writing my own toy file system with FUSE (OSXFUSE on Mac OS X and libfuse on Linux). Each time I mount the file system, FUSE calls `getattr` on some special paths, as the log shows:

```
[debug] trfs_getattr: called on path=/
[debug] trfs_getattr: called on path=/._.
[error] get_entry_attr: no entry at path /._.
[debug] trfs_getattr: called on path=/.hidden
[error] get_entry_attr: no entry at path /.hidden
[debug] trfs_getattr: called on path=/._.
[error] get_entry_attr: no entry at path /._.
[debug] trfs_getattr: called on path=/._.
[error] get_entry_attr: no entry at path /._.
[debug] trfs_getattr: called on path=/._.
[error] get_entry_attr: no entry at path /._.
[debug] trfs_getattr: called on path=/.hidden
[error] get_entry_attr: no entry at path /.hidden
```

Function `trfs_getattr()` is my own implementation of the `getattr()` callback in `struct fuse_operations`.

Function `get_entry_attr()` is used for getting the attributes of a file, and it reports error because it cannot locate the corresponding file at that path.

It seems like FUSE automatically tries to call `getattr()` on some special hidden files/directories, and this happens only on Mac OS X. The log output is normal on Linux.

Questions
* What are those special files?
* Why FUSE calls `getattr()` on those paths first?
* How to prevent this on Mac OS X?

Comment: Why do you think it's FUSE doing it rather than the OS doing it when a volume is mounted? Why do you want to prevent it? Why do you care? Just fail like for any other attempt to access a non-existent file. Surely, your file system implementation has to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

Those `._*` files are not created by fuse or your filesystem directly, it's a Mac OS X feature, see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them

Answer (score 0):

It's not Fuse, it FS itself.
It uses get_attr to check files existents at path.